# psql replace column data from another table

Tags: postgresql

New to psql and I have a simple select statement:

```
select pkid, time_created, branch, entity_name from supp_purchase_return_index where pkid > 5967 and pkid < 5971;
```

The branch column is just a unique code for each branch and instead of showing the code I want to replace it with the name of the branch from the branch table:

```
branch table:
branch, branch_name
1       branch_name1
2       branch_name2
3       branch_name3
```

My select query result should show like this:

```
pkid   time_created branch         entity_name
200014 01/01/0001   branch_name2   supplier
```

instead of:

```
pkid   time_created branch         entity_name
200014 01/01/0001   2              supplier
```

Anyone can help? Do I need to use join like inner, outer or left in which i have little knowledge.

Comment: You need to read some basics of SQL ([particulary about JOINs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))). In your case it could be something like: `select pkid, time_created, b.branch_name, entity_name from supp_purchase_return_index as s left join branch as b on b.branch = s.branch where ...`

Comment: Thank you for the links on joins,  learned a lot since reading it yesterday and was able to solve my problem.